# Does not see my app when choosing to share link/text

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I'm trying to share stuff into my app. I've got the `intent-filter` in my `Manifest.xml`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I can share into my app for videos and photos, but for some reason when I try sharing a link from the URL tab in the browser, I don't see my app listed. Why is that?

Comment: What browser, in what device?

Comment: Post more of the XML from the manifest, you may not have declared it correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm on a 4.12 Galaxy Nexus, so its still the old android browser, not chrome.
Christopher Perry: But the video and image works tho D:

Comment: Try `text/plain` instead of `text/*` for a bit and see if that helps. Or, try removing the image and video ones for a bit. I have definitely used `text/plain` as the sole MIME type on a 4.1-vintage Galaxy Nexus without a problem, picking up URLs from the browser app.

Comment: @CommonsWare specifying text/plain worked. I'm not sure why that is. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it in case other people want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use `text/plain` instead of `text/*`.

Longer answer: I have never fully grokked when and where wildcards work in `<intent-filter>`s, let alone when people try using wildcards with `setType()` or `setDataAndType()` on an `Intent`. Hence, one thing to try when you get unexpected `Intent` resolution is to try to get rid of the wildcard, if you do not strictly need it.

On the sending side, you can [use `FLAG_DEBUG_INTENT_RESOLUTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION) to try to figure out why things are not working, but that does not help when the sender is not your own code.